# Allowing Users to Upload Different Media Types in Chat

Tags: meteor

I'm currently building a messaging app with Meteor for fun, and I've stumbled into problem I'm not sure of how to solve. I want to replicate the functionality of apps like iOS Messages, WhatsApp, etc. where users can either enter text or some type of media: image, video, gif, etc.

My question is how do I structure the schema for my Messages collection, and how do I correctly store the data? My initial thought is to store the src of the media as the message content and use an `{{#If image}}` conditional to render the correct templates.

Is this the correct way to approach this problem? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to upload the media file to your server or to the cloud. The CollectionFS package should be useful to you. Once you have a shareable url for the media file you can save that in your messages collection. Alternatively you can put the _id of the media file in your messages collection as a foreign key.